# ansible load variable from file but undefine when file not found

Tags: ansible

I want to load a variable from a file. But when the file is not found, I want the variable to be empty. The problem is that this is an included_task, so this runs multiple times. When I set the variable using `set_fact` is then immutable:

```
- name: load configuration file
  ansible.builtin.include_vars:
    file: config_filename
    name: configuration_content
  when: lookup('file', config_filename, errors='warn')

- name: set component_config when file is not found
  set_fact:
    configuration_content: {}
  when: not lookup('file', component_config_file, errors='warn')
```

in this case the first run goes fine, but in the second run, if the config_filename exists, then `configuration_content` is not changed. Due to `set_fact`, the variable has become immutable and stays and empty dict forever.

The only workaround I have found now is this (but quite dirty):

```
- name: load configuration file
  ansible.builtin.include_vars:
    file: config_filename
    name: configuration_file_content
  when: lookup('file', config_filename, errors='warn')

- name: set component_config when file is found
  set_fact:
    configuration_content: "{{ configuration_file_content }}"
  when: lookup('file', component_config_file, errors='warn')

- name: set component_config when file is not found
  set_fact:
    configuration_content: {}
  when: not lookup('file', component_config_file, errors='warn')
```

I sincerly hope there is a cleaner solution for this.

Comment: Isn't there an issue in your code to start with? `when: lookup('file', config_filename, errors='warn')` will consider the content of the variable `config_filename` as the filename but `file: config_filename` will consider the file to load variable from as the string `'config_filename'`. Didn't you meant `file: "{{ config_filename }}"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell:

```yaml
- name: Set component_config
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    configuration_content: >- 
      {{ lookup('file', config_filename, errors='ignore')
      | default('{}', true) | from_yaml }}
```

Explanation:

- If `config_filename` is not found, lookup fails silently and returns an empty string
- the second parameter `true` for the `default` filter applies default for undefined and empty values.
- `from_yaml` reads in the vars from a yaml definition.

Answer (score 2):

Use Jinja to create the dictionary

```yaml
shell> cat test.yml
- set_fact:
    conf: "{{ _conf|from_yaml }}"
  vars:
    _conf: |
      {% if item is exists %}
      {{ lookup('file', item) }}
      {% else %}
      {}
      {% endif %}
- debug:
    var: conf
```

Then, given the file conf1.yml exists

```yaml
shell> cat conf1.yml 
var1: foo
var2: bar
```

The play

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: test.yml
      loop:
        - conf1.yml
        - conf2.yml
        - conf3.yml
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml
PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [include_tasks] **************************************************************************
included: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-315/test.yml for localhost => (item=conf1.yml)
included: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-315/test.yml for localhost => (item=conf2.yml)
included: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-315/test.yml for localhost => (item=conf3.yml)

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  conf:
    var1: foo
    var2: bar

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  conf: {}

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  conf: {}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=9    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

[1] You can't use the filter *ternary* because both options are evaluated before the selection. This would make this filter fail when a file is missing.

[2] [Test the path](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-paths)